# How convert a JSON string to Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, data-conversion

I already read different post regarding python conversion from str to dic but I still have problems and I can't convert my str in dictionary.

this is my original string:

````
{"faqId":1,"isPrivate":false,"question":"Question 1","answer":"# Hello world!!\r\n\r\n*   Proin elementum sollicitudin sodales.\r\n*   Nam id erat nec nibh dictum cursus.\r\n\r\n> In et urna eros. Fusce molestie, orci vel laoreet tempus, sem justo blandit magna, at volutpat velit lacus id turpis.  \r\n> Quisque malesuada sem at interdum congue. Aenean dapibus fermentum orci eu euismod.\r\n\r\n![](http://onehungrymind.com/wp-content/uploadspng)\r\n\r\n[This is an example link to nothing]()\r\n"},{"faqId":2,"isPrivate":false,"question":"Question 2","answer":"Dillinger\r\n=========\r\n\r\nDillinger is a cloud-enabled HTML5 Markdown editor.\r\n\r\n  - Type some Markdown text in the left window\r\n  - See the HTML in the right\r\n  - Magic\r\n\r\nMarkdown is a lightweight markup language based on the formatting conventions that people naturally use in email.  As [John Gruber] writes on the [Markdown site] [1]:\r\n\r\n> The overriding design goal for Markdown's\r\n> formatting syntax is to make it as readable \r\n> as possible. The idea is that a\r\n> Markdown-formatted document should be\r\n> publishable as-is, as plain text, without\r\n> looking like it's been marked up with tags\r\n> or formatting instructions.\r\n\r\nThis text you see here is *actually* written in Markdown! To get a feel for Markdown's syntax, type some text into the left window and watch the results in the right.  \r\n\r\nVersion\r\n----\r\n\r\n2.0\r\n\r\nTech\r\n-----------\r\n\r\nDillinger uses a number of open source projects to work properly:\r\n\r\n* [Ace Editor] - awesome web-based text editor\r\n* [Marked] - a super fast port of Markdown to JavaScript\r\n* [Twitter Bootstrap] - great UI boilerplate for modern web apps\r\n* [node.js] - evented I/O for the backend\r\n* [Express] - fast node.js network app framework [@tjholowaychuk]\r\n* [keymaster.js] - awesome keyboard handler lib by [@thomasfuchs]\r\n* [jQuery] - duh \r\n\r\nInstallation\r\n--------------\r\n\r\n```sh\r\ngit clone [git-repo-url] dillinger\r\ncd dillinger\r\nnpm i -d\r\nmkdir -p public/files/{md,html,pdf}\r\n```\r\n\r\n##### Configure Plugins. Instructions in following README.md files\r\n\r\n* plugins/dropbox/README.md\r\n* plugins/github/README.md\r\n* plugins/googledrive/README.md\r\n\r\n```sh\r\nnode app\r\n```\r\n\r\n\r\nLicense\r\n----\r\n\r\nMIT\r\n\r\n\r\n**Free Software, Hell Yeah!**\r\n\r\n[john gruber]:http://daringfireball.net/\r\n[@thomasfuchs]:http://twitter.com/thomasfuchs\r\n[1]:http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/\r\n[marked]:https://github.com/chjj/marked\r\n[Ace Editor]:http://ace.ajax.org\r\n[node.js]:http://nodejs.org\r\n[Twitter Bootstrap]:http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/\r\n[keymaster.js]:https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster\r\n[jQuery]:http://jquery.com\r\n[@tjholowaychuk]:http://twitter.com/tjholowaychuk\r\n[express]:http://expressjs.com\r\n"},{"faqId":4,"isPrivate":false,"question":"Question 3","answer":"# Markdown Test\r\nThis is a link: [PDF link]"}
````

I try to tidy up a bit with

```
replace("false","False")
replace("true","True")
replace('"',"'")
```

So I got back:

````
{'faqId':1,'isPrivate':False,'question':'Question 1','answer':'# Hello world!!\r\n\r\n*   Proin elementum sollicitudin sodales.\r\n*   Nam id erat nec nibh dictum cursus.\r\n\r\n> In et urna eros. Fusce molestie, orci vel laoreet tempus, sem justo blandit magna, at volutpat velit lacus id turpis.  \r\n> Quisque malesuada sem at interdum congue. Aenean dapibus fermentum orci eu euismod.\r\n\r\n![](http://onehungrymind.com/wp-content/uploads.png)\r\n\r\n[This is an example link to nothing]()\r\n'},{'faqId':2,'isPrivate':False,'question':'Question 2','answer':'Dillinger\r\n=========\r\n\r\nDillinger is a cloud-enabled HTML5 Markdown editor.\r\n\r\n  - Type some Markdown text in the left window\r\n  - See the HTML in the right\r\n  - Magic\r\n\r\nMarkdown is a lightweight markup language based on the formatting conventions that people naturally use in email.  As [John Gruber] writes on the [Markdown site] [1]:\r\n\r\n> The overriding design goal for Markdown's\r\n> formatting syntax is to make it as readable \r\n> as possible. The idea is that a\r\n> Markdown-formatted document should be\r\n> publishable as-is, as plain text, without\r\n> looking like it's been marked up with tags\r\n> or formatting instructions.\r\n\r\nThis text you see here is *actually* written in Markdown! To get a feel for Markdown's syntax, type some text into the left window and watch the results in the right.  \r\n\r\nVersion\r\n----\r\n\r\n2.0\r\n\r\nTech\r\n-----------\r\n\r\nDillinger uses a number of open source projects to work properly:\r\n\r\n* [Ace Editor] - awesome web-based text editor\r\n* [Marked] - a super fast port of Markdown to JavaScript\r\n* [Twitter Bootstrap] - great UI boilerplate for modern web apps\r\n* [node.js] - evented I/O for the backend\r\n* [Express] - fast node.js network app framework [@tjholowaychuk]\r\n* [keymaster.js] - awesome keyboard handler lib by [@thomasfuchs]\r\n* [jQuery] - duh \r\n\r\nInstallation\r\n--------------\r\n\r\n```sh\r\ngit clone [git-repo-url] dillinger\r\ncd dillinger\r\nnpm i -d\r\nmkdir -p public/files/{md,html,pdf}\r\n```\r\n\r\n##### Configure Plugins. Instructions in following README.md files\r\n\r\n* plugins/dropbox/README.md\r\n* plugins/github/README.md\r\n* plugins/googledrive/README.md\r\n\r\n```sh\r\nnode app\r\n```\r\n\r\n\r\nLicense\r\n----\r\n\r\nMIT\r\n\r\n\r\n**Free Software, Hell Yeah!**\r\n\r\n[john gruber]:http://daringfireball.net/\r\n[@thomasfuchs]:http://twitter.com/thomasfuchs\r\n[1]:http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/\r\n[marked]:https://github.com/chjj/marked\r\n[Ace Editor]:http://ace.ajax.org\r\n[node.js]:http://nodejs.org\r\n[Twitter Bootstrap]:http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/\r\n[keymaster.js]:https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster\r\n[jQuery]:http://jquery.com\r\n[@tjholowaychuk]:http://twitter.com/tjholowaychuk\r\n[express]:http://expressjs.com\r\n'},{'faqId':4,'isPrivate':False,'question':'Question 3','answer':'# Markdown Test\r\nThis is a link: [PDF link]'}
````

I'm trying different methods:

```
import json
json.loads(MY_STR)

import ast
ast.literal_eval(MY_STR)
```

etc...

but all of them give me back some kind of error, could you please help me?

Comment: Thanks so much, It worked

Comment: Just the clarify things for further readers, the problem with that you had multiple dictionaries inside your string. That's why both json and ast doesn't work. Adding brackets around everything works because it combines all the dictionaries into a list.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Surround your original string with *square brackets* to make it a valid JSON string:

```
import json

valid_json_string = "[" + your_string + "]"  # or "[{0}]".format(your_string)
data = json.loads(valid_json_string)
```